# Making the div occupy all of the rest of available space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've made a graph using SVG and put in inside a styled div. It looks awesome. Then, I added a component to the div and suddenly my great markup and styling were less great. If I uncomment the span, the svg gets 100% of the enclosing div's total height.

```
<div class="graph">
  <!--<span>I'm damaging the layout!</span>-->
  <svg id="graph1" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>
```

I want it to dynamically spread according to the available vertical space. Not sure how, though. I've tried "*" but that didn't work. I tried "auto", no luck there neither. Is there a way to acquire *the rest* or do I need to rethink the approach all together?

If the:

- div's height is a
- div's vertical padding is b and c
- the svg's top and bottom borders are d and e
- the svg's top and bottom margins are f and g
- other components take h vertical space

then I want the svg to spread across *a-(b+c+d+e+f+g+h)* pixels.

Also, I noticed that by styling the svg with a border, it gets too wide, as well. So, is it possible to fix that too in the same swing? If the:

- div's width is a
- div's horizontal padding's b and c
- the svg's left and right borders are d and e
- the svg's left and right margins are f and g

then I want it's contents to spread all over *a-(b+c+d+e+f+g)* pixels.

```
svg {
  margin: 0px;
  //border: solid;
}
```

Preferably by styling and without JS intervention. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/rd7281gb/3/).

Comment: Have you tried flexbox? Does this help? - https://jsfiddle.net/rd7281gb/5/ I didn't really follow all your descriptions. Just suggesting an idea though.

Comment: else absolute positionning quickly fix it too, for short texts. https://jsfiddle.net/rd7281gb/6/

Comment: @GCyrillus Not sure if explained clearly enough. I wish my div (the blue one) to embrace all the components in it. Then, svg, is supposed to obtain maximal width/height of the available space. So that if I append an extra span or div or whatever, decreasing the amount of available space, the svg will shrink (still occupying the rest of available space).

Comment: @Pangloss Yeah, you're getting my point just fine. For a static addition, it work perfectly. How, try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/546gt9cg/) and see what's happening if we click the div area. See? I want the svg to get smaller, resizing to the available area. Is it possible? If not, I want the div to stretch out. Still so that the svg gets shown in full.

Comment: @KonradViltersten It would be OK to stretch the div, see this updated demo - https://jsfiddle.net/546gt9cg/3/ I just changed height to min-height.

Comment: @Pangloss We're almost there. In fact, you might post the *display:flex* as the answer, especially if you can share some short description on why. As for the fiddle, take a look at [this fork](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/25yo78f2/1/) of yours. It works **precisely** the way I want except for the initial, vertical stretch of the graph. It's not reaching all the way to the bottom. However, the extension of the div is fully OK. But I need the graph to take up all the available space too. Is it doable or is our combined CSS-foo too weak?   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I think it's more and more related to resizing the svg properly, see this [article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/) hope it helps. Side note, I've heard flexbox does't work well with min-height on IE11, just be aware of it. You might be able to use CSS table or position absolute the span above the svg.

Comment: @Pangloss Yeah, I'm starting to suspect that what I want to do, needs to be dynamically controlled by JS. My aim was to have a svg that is coded with all the sized and placements inside it related to the enclosing parent's width and height. Post the part with display flex as an answer, please, so I can accept it.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't know if I should post an answer as I don't think that solves the problem. So I found that the if you set a fixed height on the svg i.e. px rather than % in css, it works. Maybe you can set the span above it to position absolute, like this - https://jsfiddle.net/etb4023u/ I don't know what you're actually going to have in that span, you can also add padding-top to the svg to avoid overlapping. I'm glad that I could help (a little). Please feel free to answer your own question or keep waiting for it or delete it if you wish.

Comment: Well, it's my question and I feel that you resolved the issue. Mainly by presenting *display:flex*. The main answer appears to be that it's not doable as such in simple CSS unless we go for JS dynamical computations and/or change the markup of the HTML. I won't force you but I'd definitely accept that as an answer.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I get that :) But still I don't feel to do it. Maybe I'm just being lazy, haha.

Comment: How does this one look? https://jsfiddle.net/25yo78f2/4/